# chrome.tabs.query does not find match if url property is an array

Tags: arrays, google-chrome, url, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I'm building a chrome extension and trying to get an array of tabs using chrome.tabs.query({url: arrayOfUrls}):

```
chrome.tabs.query({url: this.tabUrlsList}, function(tabs){
            var ids = [];
            if(tabs){   
                //creates an array of intergers (tab ids)

                for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++){
                    ids[i] = tabs[i].id;

                }
                console.log(tabs.length)
                console.log(ids)
                \\move stuff around using the tabs' ids
```

The problem is when the url array has more than one google page (say http://mail, http://developer, chrome://extensions), query returns the id for only one of them. Does anybody know what to do?
Thanks

Comment: Does your manifest include the tabs permission, and what's an example of the array you are passing?

Comment: Hi John, I do have the tabs permission, an example is an array of urls taken from the browser say: 
["https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50160123/chrome-tabs-query-does-not-find-match-if-url-property-is-an-array","chrome://extensions","https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox"] .
please see the edit. In this example array, query will return an id only for "extensions" because it came first, and nothing for gmail. the stackoverflow page will also be returned normally

Comment: Josh! sorry. please see the edit in the original question:)